# R - S3 or S4 for functions with single arguments?

Tags: r, r-s4

My understanding of the two main OOP systems in R is that S3 is very simple but not very rigorous for validity whereas S4 is more rigorous but more complex.  Generally, the guidelines I have seen are if your function depends on multiple arguments being certain types then you almost always want to go with S4.

Now with the `t` generic, there is only a single argument.  Would it be recommended to always create new S3 method for a new class?  Would there be any drawback to doing an S4 method so there could be additional checks on additional slots within a class?  Just curious on recommended practice in situations like this.

My question is not necessarily what people prefer but if there **is a logical basis to choosing one over the other** in this case or if it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Recommendations would really just be opinion based and such questions are off topic for Stack Overflow. It would help if you had a more specific question.

Comment: @MrFlick My question is more if this is just preference based or if there is logic to one method or the other.  In this particular case I thought the question was appropriate.